# how to use parameters of class_ from boost.python

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

The first question:
The class_ class has four parameters.

```
class template class_<T, Bases, HeldType, NonCopyable>
```

I don't understand the parameters of Bases and HeldType.How to use the
parameters.
this doc: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html

The second question:
I have to make a python function as callback of a c++ function.How to
do?Where can I find some examples??

Comment: `Bases` - base classes for T in python as in C++. `HeldType` in most cases is T.

Comment: Bases C++ base classes from T?HeldType is a class derived from T.But I don't know what work and effect with the two parameters.

Comment: Not from T. Bases classes of T.

Comment: If T is a class derived,must work with parameter of Bases？The HeldType derived from T,what did it do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HeldType is usefull, if you want to use a special object to hold your object. For e.g. if you use shared_ptr<> inside your implementation you can use this as HeldType.

If you have no idea what shared_ptr are, just google for them, they are a nice tool.

Further descriptions as an example for the shared_ptr<> as HeldType can be found here:
[Python Wiki, deailing with smart pointers](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/PointersAndSmartPointers)